# Move files and rename - one-liner

Tags: linux, bash

I'm encountering many files with the same content and the same name on some of my servers. I need to quarantine these files for analysis so I can't just remove the duplicates. The OS is Linux (centos and ubuntu).

I enumerate the file names and locations and put them into a text file.

Then I do a for statement to move the files to quarantine.

```
for file in $(cat bad-stuff.txt); do mv $file /quarantine ;done
```

The problem is that they have the same file name and I just need to add something unique to the filename to get it to save properly. I'm sure it's something simple but I'm not good with regex. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "with the same content and the same name" -> why do you care about the copies then? Unless they don't necessarily have the same content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this

```
for file in $(cat bad-stuff.txt); do mv $file /quarantine/$file.`date -u +%s%N`; done
```

You'll get everyfile with a timestamp appended (in nanoseconds).

Comment: Not asked. Just add `basename` as:

`for file in $(cat bad-stuff.txt); do cp $file /quarantine/$(basename $file).\`date -u +%s%N\`; done`

It fails on spaces too but I'll not will do a one liner if gets more complicated than that.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using Linux, you can take advantage of GNU mv's `--backup`.

```
while read -r file
do 
    mv --backup=numbered "$file" "/quarantine"
done < "bad-stuff.txt"
```

Here's an example that shows how it works:

```
$ cat bad-stuff.txt 
./c/foo
./d/foo
./a/foo
./b/foo
$ while read -r file; do mv --backup=numbered "$file" "./quarantine"; done < "bad-stuff.txt"
$ ls quarantine/
foo  foo.~1~  foo.~2~  foo.~3~
$
```

Comment: Setting `IFS` without also using the non-standard `-d` option with `read` has no real effect, since the entire line is read into the variable `file`, regardless of how that line might be split into words.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Any way to just use my current one-liner and just rename the duplicates?

Comment: @user1675042 You can use the same command. But you shouldn't unless you can guarantee filenames have no spaces in them. Think about what happens if the file is named "random_name space name_of_file_that_shouldn_t_be_removed" (offending file will not be touched, but your other file will be moved away instead).

Comment: That didn't work. It is not renaming each instance of the file just replacing the same file over and over. Good thing I tested first. lol

Comment: @user1675042 What exactly did you try and what system are you using? This method should work with any reasonable linux system. Maybe there was some silly mistake?

Comment: It's a Ubuntu 2.6.32 system. I used the while statement you posted and it didn't work. I'll probably just try to use perl or python to script it. Just wanted a one-liner I could use on the fly since this is a common thing for my job.

Comment: while IFS='' read -r file; do mv --backup=numbered "$file" "test/final/"; done < p.txt

Comment: @user1675042 Did you get any errors? What was the contents of p.txt and what did test/final/ contain afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new file name composed by the `directory` and the `filename`. Thus you can add one more argument in your original code:

```
for ...; do mv $file /quarantine/$(echo $file | sed 's:/:_:g') ; done
```

Please note that you should replace the `_` with a proper character which is special enough.